# how to check for multiple switch statement in c#

Tags: c#

i need to check more than one statement in switch statement to evalute
like

```
 int a=5; 
 switch(a) 
 { 
     case 4,5:
         console.write("its from 4 to 5);
         break; 
 }
```

Answer (score 12):

You want to do:

```
case 4:
case 5:
//Code goes here.
break;
```

Remember though C# doesn't allow fall through so you can't do:

```
    case 4:
    //Do some stuff here
    //fall through to 5
    case 5:
    //Code goes here.
    break;
```

Comment: This "feature" really irritates me, I don't understand why Microsoft killed case fall through!

Comment: @Chris you know there are times when I think about where it would come in handy and would make life easier, but I really don't miss it.  I've seen too many times where people make a mistake on the fall through statement, and I have to spend hours trying to track down a problem.  I think in the long run, not having it saves me time.

Comment: C# supports "goto case n;" so you can end case 4 with "goto case 5;" and it is equivalent to the C semantics (but ugly).

Comment: @Chris: Because general fallthrough is 1% usefull and produces 99% more coding errors.

Comment: @Foxfire so make a compiler warning for it, or make a 2nd switch statement like switchf for fall through. Microsoft shouldn't have decided we're too stupid to use case fall through correctly. @plinth The goto statement is really a poor fix for it.

Comment: @Chris: And what would a warning help you? Do you want to write code that only compiles with hundereds of warnings? And just about anybody probably uses WarningAsError anyways.

Answer (score 3):

In c# you stack cases to do this:

```
case 4:
case 5:
   //do something
   break;
case 6:
   //do something
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

This allows you to execute multiple cases for 1 value.

```
int a=5; 
 switch(a) 
 { 
     case 4:
        // Do work here
        goto case 5;
     case 5:
         console.write("its from 4 to 5);
         break; 
 }
```

or

This is giving a case two labels.

```
 switch(a) 
 { 
     case 4:
     case 5:
         console.write("its from 4 to 5);
         break; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how..

```
 int a=5; 
 switch(a) 
 { 
     case 4:
     case 5:
         console.write("its from 4 to 5);
         break; 
 }
```